# How to force DHCP on all phyiscal ports, including Disconnected Media ports, with WMIC

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, wmic

Could anyone help me force all network adapters to be DHCP whether connected or disconnected.

I am relatively new and very novice in batch and I have been working on something to set fixed ipv4 details based on variable Ethernet adapter names.  It has been cobbled together from other people's solutions to various problems on here.  I am sure there are much more eloquent and elegant ways of doing this and happy to be pointed that way but I would like to try and figure this out.

The idea was to have a call batch script in the startup folder of a OOBE windows machine.  Search the connected adapter, irrelevant of the name of said port, set the IP address as static and rest of the details were fixed.  I wrote the batch in such a way as to create various IP profiles using  variables to create the profile to set the fixed details i.e. a batch to write a batch

As an exercise I was thinking if I were to move the machine and plug in a different adapter on the same machine.  How would I have a disconnected adapter with the IP address I want to use switch to DHCP.  This would free up the address to search for connected adapter as per the rest of the script.  This is where the script fails. I can have the connected adapter switch tp DHCP, disable and enable correctly.

`WMIC NICConfig Where "IPEnabled='True' and DHCPEnabled='FALSE'" Call EnableDHCP`
this works but only on the connected adapter.

But I am trying to flush out the IP address on the disconnected adapter to use on the connected adapter.  So far I've tried

`WMIC NICConfig Where NetConnectionID=7 Call EnableDHCP`

returns a `"Description = Invalid query"`

`WMIC NICConfig Where "PhysicalAdapter='True'" Call EnableDHCP`

returns a `"Description = Invalid query"`

`WMIC NICConfig Where "DHCPEnabled='FALSE'" Call EnableDHCP`

returns `{ReturnValue = 84;};`  I thought this would search for adapters that were not DHCP and change to to be DHCP but I think the adapter has to be connected.

When I use

`WMIC NICConfig Where "PhysicalAdapter='True'" Call /?`

`EnableDHCP` looks to be an option but gives a `"Description = Invalid query"`

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

I can also post the entire script if anyone is interested in it but will leave it off until requested.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The return value of `84` meant that the IP wasn't enabled on that adapter configuration and therefore DHCP couldn't be enabled. You then specified the same command including only those where the IP was enabled, and didn't get the error message. Given that your question states, `Search the connected port, irrelevant of the name of said port` and you've stated that the command `works but only on the connected port`, could explain what you mean by `port`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean physical adapter.  "The return value of  ```84 ``` meant that the IP wasn't enabled"  The adapter is set to a static IP but would not have a cable plugged in.  Does ```IPEnabled``` mean connected? 

So the script in it's current state can find the connected adapter (say adapter1) and apply the fixed settings and ask to set the IP.  But if the computer was moved and adapter2 was plugged in, the script is ran again it will try do the same thing but adapter1 will have the IP address that is required for that computer.  I am looking to "clear" adapter1's details by DHCPing it.

Comment: No, I'm sorry it doesn't, if wmi cannot find the adapter, how do you expect it to change the configuration data for it?

Comment: Sorry for the convoluted post and thank you for the reply.  Is there a way clearing the IP address on the disconnected adapters (I was trying to do this by setting it to DHCP) to free up the IP address to use on the connected adapter which happens further down in the script.  I think this is the simplest way of saying it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
I was going about it the complete wrong way.
I was trying to clear all adapters fixed ip addresses by "forcing" the physical adapter to DCHP weather connected or disconnected.

But if I have had said

```
netsh int ip reset
wmic path win32_networkadapter where PhysicalAdapter=True call disable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where PhysicalAdapter=True call enable
```

This achieves what I want.  This clears the IP, subnet and gateway.  Sometimes the solution is much easier than expected.

Is there a way to clear the DNS information too for all physical adapters, without knowing their names, so that if IPV4 properties is open no information would be there?